# How to set the tone of large passages of text without italics?

Tags: typography, typefaces, readability

Here and there in my article, there are paragraphs that need to set a different tone. So far I’ve used italic Times New Roman and indented the paragraph:

[image]

This looks good if it’s one line sentence or a five-line paragraph. But for a page-long preamble it seems that [large blocks of italic text are harder to read](https://www.quora.com/Do-italics-decrease-readability#):

[image]

**Is there a way to set the tone for the preamble the same as the other paragraphs? A different typeface maybe? Or is de-italicizing the only way?**

Indents, rules, flourishes are just for making a distinction, not really setting the tone of the text as they don’t change the typeface. Only italic or a font change can do that, I think.

Comment: Print or digital **does** make a difference. Body text is often best as a serif for print and sans serif for digital reading.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet why is that? Surely that's the default font of Office for a reason, right?

Comment: @Scott I read that it has been tested and concluded that it doesn't matter?

Comment: It matters. Most things you read focus on whether one or the other is "hard to read". Neither is "hard to read" in either situation. But one is more conducive to reading given the environment. It's not "hard" to swim a lap in a pool, but it's easier with a float device.

Comment: After the Edit: Better question overall, but I fear it's still a bit too opinion-based. There are *many* variations which could offset a preamble without italics - indents, rules, font-changes, flourishes, etc.

Comment: @Scott what would the rules apply for preamble?

Comment: Rules as in geometric shapes or lines for division.... not as a reference to restrictions.

Comment: @Scott hmm, I see that indents, rules, flourishes are just for making distinction, not setting the tone of the text. Only italic or font-change can do that I think, and these are what the question asks. Would this reduce the variations that make this question too opinion-based?

Comment: Well, the definition of "tone of the text" is **very** subjective. Offsetting a block of text changes it's "tone". Altering the size of the text, changes its "tone". This is another place where it's more the *art* of perception, not "follow these guidelines" science. It is *very hard* to be a "designer" if you are overly concerned about living up to some rulebook or guidelines. Guidelines should be read, understood, ingested.. then never reviewed again. You want them as a general footing, but the **only** absolutes in design are adhering to the *technical* requirements for output/reproduction.

Comment: @Scott yes, I want to talk about a science of perception, not an art of perception. But that's called psychology/cognitive science already, and I don't have much knowledge on that. Person for my ignorance, but it seems that most designers don't know this much, too?

Comment: Ooker.. my point is that it's **not** science. You **can't** definitively state what is or is not correct. What one viewer likes another will dislike. You may be searching for absolutes where there simply are *none*.

Comment: my 2¢: don't change from sans serif to serif just for differentiation purposes. It's really brain-scrambling. I can feel my eyeballs changing gears just looking at your screenshot, and it's painful.

Comment: readability of italics sucks indeed. I personally would use bold or semibold to add some accent. I'd also set the font size slightly smaller then body text (if using bold). Colored text or light background color may work as well.